# Expand and Contract UITableView row one at a time swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am working on expanding and collapsing table view cell. The current situation works well , where assume Row-0 is tapped a new row is added at index-1 and shown as expanded and when again Row-0 is tapped the expanded index-1 is collapsed. If Row-0 is in expanded state and even if I tap on another Row, the row will expand keeping both open at the same time.
Here is what I want to change, I want to contract any other row which is open when I tap on another row. i.e. One row should be open at a time. Please see the below code for ref which I tried using an array to detect which row is currently expanded, this works only if we go sequentially else it starts deleting the contracted rows. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank You !

```
 public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
  {        

  if expandCellArray.object(at: indexPath.row) as! String == "contract"
    {
        for i in 0 ..< self.expandCellArray.count
        {
            if expandCellArray.object(at: i) as! String == "expanded"
            {
                self.contractCell(tableView: tableView, index: i)
                self.expandCellArray.replaceObject(at: i, with: "contract")
                print("Updated Expand Cell array",expandCellArray)
            }
        }
        self.expandCell(tableView: tableView, index: indexPath.row)
        self.expandCellArray.replaceObject(at: indexPath.row, with: "expanded")
        print("Updated Expand Cell array",expandCellArray)

    }
    else
    {
        self.contractCell(tableView: tableView, index: self.selectedIndexPath.row)
    }
 }
```

Function to Expand Row

```
private func expandCell(tableView: UITableView, index: Int)
 {
        if (dataArray[index]?.title) != nil {
            dataArray.insert(nil, at: index + 1)
            myTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index + 1, section: 0)], with: .none)
    }

 }
```

Function to Contract row

```
private func contractCell(tableView: UITableView, index: Int)
 {
    if (dataArray[index]?.title) != nil {
        dataArray.remove(at: index + 1)
        myTableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index + 1, section: 0 )], with: .none)
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding or removing cells is tricky because you have to handle the indexes. Alternatively, a simpler implementation of this is to use [expandable sections](https://www.appcoda.com/expandable-table-view/).

Instead of adding and deleting, you just simply showing and hiding them with animation. If you want to keep only one section open, when user click on another section, simply collapse the opened section and do section reload on both sections(The one that user clicked and the one that is currently open)